# Function and One to One function

Tags: functions, relations

Do one-to-one functions have to comply to the rules of a function? Does this explain why y^2=x is not a part of the one-to-one function? And why do only one-to-one functions are inverse functions?

Comment: Yes, a "one to one **function**" is a **function**.  It says so right there!   In $y^2= x$, y is not a function of x, but x **is** a function of y!

Comment: Umm, is a function a function???

Comment: @copper.hat Not sure your sarcastic comment is appropriate. Compare with Ross Millikan's detailed answer and comments.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin I am rarely appropriate. However, my remark was not sarcastic; rather quizzical.

Answer (score 1):

Read the definitions carefully.  Yes, a one-to-one function has to comply with the rules of a function.  One-to-one is and adjective modifying function, so you start with a function and impose the requirement of one-to-one.  Only one-to-one functions have inverses because if there are $a\neq b$ with $f(a)=f(b)$ (so the function is not one-to-one) you don't have a single answer for $f^{-1}(f(a))=a$ because it could be $f^{-1}(f(b))=b$

Comment: Isn't inverse function just about switching the x values with the y values. I mean if you could inverse on a parabola, would you just be switching the positions?

Comment: If you switch the values on a parabola, you get two $y$ values for each $x$, so it is not a function.  For the parabola $y=x^2$, you get $x=\pm \sqrt y$, which has two solutions for $y \gt 0$ and no solutions for $y \lt 0$, so it is not a function.  In my last sentence, in $y=x$ you have $a=1, b=-1$ with $a^2=b^2$, so there is not a single inverse for $1$

Comment: What is the use of inverse function anyway?

Comment: The use is that it enables you to go the other way.  If you have $y=$ some function of $x$ you can plug in $x$ and get $y$.  Sometimes you have $y$ and want to get $x$.  If there is an inverse function, you can do that.  If not, you can't guarantee it.